# How to mix two int arrays into unique xy coordinates Map?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, hashmap

Consider this:

```
public Map<Integer, Point> setXY(int[] x, int[] y) {
     Point point;
     Map<Integer, Point> xy = new HashMap<Integer, Point>();
     int key = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
          for(int j = 0; j < y.length; j++) {
               point = new Point(x[i], y[j]);
               xy.put(key, point);
               key++;
          }
     }
     return xy;
}
```

I have two int arrays of different length and I try to create unique coordinates for "n" Point objects. "n" means value of "x.length + y.length" (e.g. n = x[3] + y[5]). Then I'm adding those objects to my hashmap. The problem is, that this nested "for" instruction creates for "i = 2" for example five points with coords: (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4) and (2, 5). What I want to achieve is fully randomization of points creations with use of those two given "x" & "y" arrays. Do you have any ideas?

EDIT

I'm considering now a posibility of randomization only for Map key value. E. g. I have 400 objects in the map so it will be enough if I would know how to get random unique(!) values from 0-400 range. Of course values can't repeat. It's a key to whole thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Collections there is a shuffle method which you can use to get elements in random order of an array but unique.

```
Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(y));
```

This will shuffle the order of elements in array y. Then use for loop to iterate.

Comment: It's worthless cause I have specified key values for my Hashmap, e. g. from 0 to 100. In this case when I'll shuffle my Map than I'll change nothing, cause at the moment of getting a specific element from the map I have to use a key.

Comment: Yes but the value corresponding to that key will be random, which seems to be what you want.

Comment: You can get the key values as a list and shuffle then iterate through it.

Comment: @arynaq, I didn't make it, you get the jump on me :) Yeah, that will work now I can see it. So basically I'll create an array in range of my Map length (n) with values in it from "0" to 0+1, 0+2...0+n. Next I'll shuffle it. And then just use indexes of that new shuffled array like my keys for Map :) Brilliant, thank you guys!